# Is better a switch or a const table? (embedded SW)

Tags: c, arrays, switch-statement, embedded

I wonder if, when it is possible, Is it more efficient a switch or a const table?

For example, what would perform better:

```
switch(input) {
  case 0: value = VALUE_0;
    break;
  case 1: value = VALUE_1;
    break;
  case 2: value = VALUE_2;
    break;
  case 3: value = VALUE_3;
    break;
  case 4: value = VALUE_4;
    break;
  case 5: value = VALUE_5;
    break;
  case 6: value = VALUE_6;
    break;
  default:    
    break;
}
```

Or something like this:

```
const uint8_t INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE[N_VALUE] = {
    VALUE_0,
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2,
    VALUE_3,
    VALUE_4,
    VALUE_5,
    VALUE_6,
}
...
...
value = INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE[input];
```

I have shown a dummy example, but I have also the code for using a switch calling different functions or a function pointer table.

The code is for is for a 8bits micro (I don'w know if it makes any difference for this topic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you should consider disassembling the compiled code to see what's actually getting generated, but I'd expect that you end up with less code in the second case, and there's less branching.

In the first case, there are seven assignment statements, and a bunch of jumps (out of the switch statement).  In the second, there's one array reference, and one assignment.  Since your cases are all contiguous, it's easy to handle the default case:

```
value = ( input < 6 ) ? INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE[input] : default_value;
```

Let's look at some assembly.  This is compiled with `gcc -S`, version 4.6.3, so it's not the same as the assembly you'd get, but we should getting the same general kind of result.  This answer won't *absolutely* answer the question of which will be better in your case;  you'll have to do some tests on your own, but it looks pretty sure that the table is going to be preferable.

### The `switch` option:

We'll start with the `switch`:

```
void switch_input( int input ) {
  switch(input) {
  case 0: value = VALUE_0;
    break;
  case 1: value = VALUE_1;
    break;
  case 2: value = VALUE_2;
    break;
  case 3: value = VALUE_3;
    break;
  case 4: value = VALUE_4;
    break;
  case 5: value = VALUE_5;
    break;
  case 6: value = VALUE_6;
    break;
  default: value = VALUE_DEFAULT;
    break;
  }
}
```

This has lots of jumps in it, as there are seven different assignments, and based on the value of `input`, we have to be able to jump to each one, and then jump to the end of the `switch`.

```
switch_input:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    cmpl    $6, -4(%rbp)
    ja  .L2
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movq    .L10(,%rax,8), %rax
    jmp *%rax
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
    .align 4
.L10:
    .quad   .L3
    .quad   .L4
    .quad   .L5
    .quad   .L6
    .quad   .L7
    .quad   .L8
    .quad   .L9
    .text
.L3:
    movl    $0, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L4:
    movl    $1, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L5:
    movl    $2, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L6:
    movl    $3, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L7:
    movl    $4, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L8:
    movl    $5, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L9:
    movl    $6, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L2:
    movl    $-1, value(%rip)
    nop
.L1:
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

### The table option

The table option can use just a single assignment, and instead having lots of *code* that we can jump to, we just need a table of values.  We don't need to jump into that table, either;  we just need to compute an index, and then unconditionally load a value from it.

```
void index_input( int input ) {
  value = ( input < N_VALUE ) ? INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE[input] : VALUE_DEFAULT;
}
```

(Yes, we really should be using an unsigned integer there so that we know it won't be less than zero.)

```
index_input:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    cmpl    $5, -4(%rbp)
    jg  .L13
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movl    INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE(,%rax,4), %eax
    jmp .L14
.L13:
    movl    $-1, %eax
.L14:
    movl    %eax, value(%rip)
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

### Appendix

#### The C code (example.c)

```
int value;

#define N_VALUE 7

#define VALUE_0 0
#define VALUE_1 1
#define VALUE_2 2
#define VALUE_3 3
#define VALUE_4 4
#define VALUE_5 5
#define VALUE_6 6
#define VALUE_DEFAULT -1

void switch_input( int input ) {
  switch(input) {
  case 0: value = VALUE_0;
    break;
  case 1: value = VALUE_1;
    break;
  case 2: value = VALUE_2;
    break;
  case 3: value = VALUE_3;
    break;
  case 4: value = VALUE_4;
    break;
  case 5: value = VALUE_5;
    break;
  case 6: value = VALUE_6;
    break;
  default: value = VALUE_DEFAULT;
    break;
  }
}

const int INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE[N_VALUE] = {
  VALUE_0,
  VALUE_1,
  VALUE_2,
  VALUE_3,
  VALUE_4,
  VALUE_5,
  VALUE_6
};

void index_input( int input ) {
  value = ( input < 6 ) ? INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE[input] : VALUE_DEFAULT;
}
```

#### The assembly (example.s)

Generated by `gcc -S`.

```
    .file   "example.c"
    .comm   value,4,4
    .text
    .globl  switch_input
    .type   switch_input, @function
switch_input:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    cmpl    $6, -4(%rbp)
    ja  .L2
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movq    .L10(,%rax,8), %rax
    jmp *%rax
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
    .align 4
.L10:
    .quad   .L3
    .quad   .L4
    .quad   .L5
    .quad   .L6
    .quad   .L7
    .quad   .L8
    .quad   .L9
    .text
.L3:
    movl    $0, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L4:
    movl    $1, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L5:
    movl    $2, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L6:
    movl    $3, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L7:
    movl    $4, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L8:
    movl    $5, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L9:
    movl    $6, value(%rip)
    jmp .L1
.L2:
    movl    $-1, value(%rip)
    nop
.L1:
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   switch_input, .-switch_input
    .globl  INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE
    .section    .rodata
    .align 16
    .type   INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE, @object
    .size   INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE, 28
INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE:
    .long   0
    .long   1
    .long   2
    .long   3
    .long   4
    .long   5
    .long   6
    .text
    .globl  index_input
    .type   index_input, @function
index_input:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    cmpl    $5, -4(%rbp)
    jg  .L13
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movl    INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE(,%rax,4), %eax
    jmp .L14
.L13:
    movl    $-1, %eax
.L14:
    movl    %eax, value(%rip)
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   index_input, .-index_input
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probably quite unlikely that the switch will get optimized into something as efficient as the table lookup. It is probably safe to assume that the table is faster, but you have to check on your specific system.

Had it been an array of function pointers, where each function pointer represents a `case`, it would have been another story however. Because it is very likely that a decent compiler optimizes a switch with adjacent number inputs into such a function-pointer table.

Since you mention 8-bit MCUs, it might be quite relevant to make manual code optimizations. Sadly, most mainstream 8-bit MCU compilers are poor at code optimization (and often rather poor at standard compliance as well).

Answer (score 1):

The second one is more efficient, but lacks overflow protection. Unless you are certain that `input` is between `0` and `6` you would need a guard:

```
if (input >= 0 && input < 7) {
    value = INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE[input];
}
```

If you need the guard, it will use up some of the performance advantage.

Answer (score 0):

It's depending on application. I prefer switch because we can have a default case for doing something if all cases fails.

Comment: But in performing (speed, CPU requirements..) is there any significant difference?

Answer (score 0):

Using local table surely is much more conservative in cpu cycles (CPE), and memory consumption. You can easily deduce it, just by looking at its assembly code.

An additional explanation you can find [here](https://coderwall.com/p/6e7rea)

Answer (score 0):

It depends, you should time it. A compact 0-based table like yours can have a **single** `if` as a guard:

```
if ((unsigned)input <= 6) {
   value = INPUT_TO_VALUE_TABLE[input];
}
```

(because negative values of `input` are seen here as big positive values)

If you don't need the guard, the table is most probably the fastest. If you need it... it depends.

On some hardware this trick for checking a range with a single `if` (instead of 2) is also useful:

```
value = (unsigned)(input - min) <= max - min ? table[input] : default_value;
```

(obviously faster if max and min are constants, or, at least, `max - min` can be precalculated)